# Saving jsignature image no longer transparent

Tags: image, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

How can I save this base64 image from a jsignature to a transparent ping? I used to be able to successfully save the image with a transparent background and now it will only save with a black background. I am not sure what broke after one of the recent two ColdFusion or Java updates. (I'm running Cold Fusion 2016 update 10)  The image data is passed into local.signaturedata via a form field & POST.

```
<cfimage action="read" source="#imageReadBase64(local.signaturedata)#" name="local.imgCanvas"> <!--- png --->
<cfset ImageResize(local.imgCanvas,"",local.height)> <!--- png --->
<cfset local.bimg = imageGetBufferedImage(local.imgCanvas)>
<!--- RGB --->
<cfset local.rCS = createObject("java","java.awt.color.ColorSpace").CS_sRGB><!--- PROD: CS_sRGB, TEST: CS_LINEAR_RGB, TYPE_RGB, TYPE_INT_ARGB --->
<cfset local.rgb = createObject("java","java.awt.color.ColorSpace").getInstance(local.rCS)>

<cfset local.convert = createObject("java","java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp").init(local.rgb,javaCast("null",""))>

<cfset local.newImage = local.convert.filter(local.bimg, javaCast("null",""))>
<cfset local.imgCanvasConverted = imageNew(local.newImage)><!--- PROD: imageNew(local.newImage) --->

data:image/png;base64,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
```

Comment: Are you saying it works with a different version of CF and, which versions and update levels? Could you post a sample signature string someone can test? If it's too large for S.O. use something like gist or pastebin.

Comment: Ageax the sample signature string is at the bottom of the code, sorry that's confusing. You can copy/ paste that directly into an img tag in an html page to see the image with a transparent background. The code hasn't changed. It works in Cold Fusion 2016 not another version. A few updates ago the resulting image had a transparent background. Now the image has a black background. Maybe the underlying java classes have changed?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that, but it sounds like there is patch (answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We fixed this issue just after the update release. We can share the patch with you. Can you please send an email at cf.install@adobe.com.

Thanks,
Priyank

Comment: For anyone else that encounters the issue, which 2016 update has this problem?

Comment: Priyank's patch resolved the issue. I was running Cold Fusion 2016 update 10. After installing the patch jsignature images returned to a transparent background. Please email Priyank at Adobe to obtain the patch. The instructions were to place the patch in the cfusion\lib\updates directory and restart the CF service.

Comment: How to get the patch? I'm also facing same problem.